# Добавление данных в БД с другого окна

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt5

На первом изображении, при нажатии на кнопку `"Вход"`, программа подключается к БД и переходит на след. окно(изображение 2).

Теперь вопрос: как  при нажатии на кнопку `"Добавить клиента"` (оно перекидывает на еще одно окно, 3 изображение) добавить данные, которые ввели в БД?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: все добавление делается при нажатии на кнопку `"Готово"`

Comment: Вариант qtStyle: при нажатии "Готово" вызывается сигнал, передающий данные для вставки в БД в основное окно через сигнал-слот, в слоте отправляет в БД.
Вариант 2: при открытии нового окна передать ему объект БД, чтоб при нажатии "Готово" в третьем окне отравить данные в БД.

Comment: Хорошо. А как передать объект БД?)

Comment: Окна - это интерфейс. Объекты БД и прочие данные не должны быть частью окон. Выносите их всех в отдельный контекст, и предоставляйте окнам для работы ссылку на него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с базой данных вполне достаточно одного объекта, поэтому предлагаю создать класс-обертку по шаблону `Singleton`:

```
class MyDatabase {
public:
    static MyDatabase& instance() {
        static MyDatabase self;
        return self;
    }
    // Создать соединение с БД
    bool open() {
        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
        db.setHostName("hostname");
        db.setDatabaseName("my.db");
        return db.open();
    }
    // Есть ли соединение
    bool isOpen() const;

    // Функции коммуникации с БД 
    // select()
    // insert()
    // remove()
}
```

Архитектуру приложения можно организовать множеством способов. Судя, по вашим картинкам предлагаю следующий подход:

```
// Диалог создания клиента
class CreateClientDialog {
...
}

class MainWindow {
public:
    MainWindow() {
        // соединяем сигнал клика кнопки с лямбдой С++11
        connect(ui->pushButtonNewClient, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
            CreateClientDialog dialog;
            // Показываем диалог и если пользователь нажал "Готово",
            // диалог должен вернуть Qt::Accepted
            if ( dialog.exec() == Qt::Accepted) {
                auto& db = MyDatabase::instance();
                
                // если пользователь добавился без проблем, то возращаем id > 0
                // иначе, например -1, либо 
                // бросаем исключение (тогда вызов надо обернуть в try ... catch)
                int id = db.insert(
                    dialog.name(),
                    dialog.lastName(),
                    dialog.phone() 
                ); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

и так далее